# Java Async I/O with NIO2: Does AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept give you an active AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, asynchronous, asyncsocket, nio2

For server.accept I wrote a completion handler that has the  parameters.

When the handler is invoked via the accept method, does that mean the AsynchronousSocketChannel is now conneted?

Or do I have to invoke the AsynchronousSocketChannel.connect method?

Right now what I think is going on is that AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept accepts a connection (and stores it in the AsynchronousSocketChannel parameter) , and that AsynchronousSocketChannel.connect also initiates a connection from server to client (stores in the socket channel).

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

> When the handler is invoked via the accept method, does that mean the AsynchronousSocketChannel is now conneted?

Yes.

> Or do I have to invoke the AsynchronousSocketChannel.connect method?

No.

> Right now what I think is going on is that AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept accepts a connection (and stores it in the AsynchronousSocketChannel parameter)

Yes.

> and that AsynchronousSocketChannel.connect also initiates a connection from server to client (stores in the socket channel).

No. Obviously you haven't tried it. It would fail.

`accept()` is for servers. `connect()` is for clients.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was thinking. I am working on my 1st barebones implementation & design. It sounds like what I have will work once I write the test client.